# Align Leading Edges of View with constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I am having an `UIImageView` (say **imageView1**) and a `UITextView`(say **textView1**) which have to be displayed vertically (one [**imageView1**] below the other [**textView1**]) beginning with the same margin position as of **textView1**. I have to achieve this through autolayout programmatically.

I know that this can be done by setting the  vertical constraints like below for both the views.

```
NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[textView1]"
```

But the problem I have here is I already have many text views(**textView2**, **textView3**) arranged in horizontal before and after this **textView1**.

I have already added many autolayout constraints to this **textView1** through storyboard. Based on the different screen size and orientation the **textView1** margin differs as per the constraints that are provided on the storyboard for this.

Now how can I provide the autolayout constraint programmatically in such a way that my **imageView1** is to align in par vertically with the same margin as that of **textView1**?

p.s: **imageView1** is created programmatically in code but where as all other views that I mentioned above are created through storyboard.

> **+ Adding images for easy understanding**

[image]

In the image, **imageView1** is the **UI** Image. I have created it in storyboard just for understanding purpose but in real it will be created programmatically and this have to be aligned to the margin of `UITextView` (**textView1**) present below it.

[image]

This is the constraint that I want to create it through programmatically(In case this is the real question here :).

This constraint is to always make sure that **imageView1** and **textView1** start originating from the same margin.

**How to define this constraint programmatically ?**

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit more, maybe some pics (or drawing) of what is your goal.

Comment: @HugoAlonso : Updated with some more details. Please check now.

Comment: All right, I edited your question for better understanding, I'm taking a look, but my understanding is in swift, I wil be trying to explain you the steps to achieve such result.

Comment: What's the point in adding this programmatically if you have already setted many others via Storyboard? ..have you tried just hiding that view or setting it's height into zero when you don't want to show the image? This way you can have all your constraints in Storyboard.

Comment: @HugoAlonso : Because I want to create N number of UIImageViews dynamically based on the count and have to show it in screen. As per your suggestion now I am temporarily creating the UIImageView through storyboard and hiding it in code.Thanks for this idea ! But although apt solution would be creating it programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using the visual format, you can just instantiate a constraint directly, e.g.

```
[NSLayoutConstraint
    constraintWithItem:imageView1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
    toItem:textView1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
    multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Masonry for setting constraints programmatically.It is very easy to use and reduce lots of complexities for the user.

```
 https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry
```

Comment: I am unable to figure out my required constraint over there in Masonry. Can you help me out there? I have added some image links for clear understanding of the question.

Answer (score 0):

...you can try to build an `UIView`, set the constraints that it will need, and use it as a placeholder for your `UIImageView`s.(*later you can add them inside of such a view*) or, by the otherside, using an `UICollectionView` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the options argument in 
`constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views:` check [Apple Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLayoutConstraint/constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views:).

Your code might be as follows

```
NSString* leadingConstraintsExpression = @"V:[imageView1][textView1]";

NSDictionary* viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imageView1,textView1);

NSArray* leadingConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint 
                                  constraintsWithVisualFormat:leadingConstraintsExpression
                                                      options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading 
                                                      metrics:nil 
                                                        views:viewsDictionary];

[self.view addConstraints:leadingConstraints];
```